# How to setup Storybook with Expo and Web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, storybook

I am trying to setup react native stories on expo which is working fine on the device but I am unable to set it up for the web. I want the components to render on the Web too. Can you please suggest any guide or configuration for that?

This is my storybook configuration: https://github.com/iamshadmirza/RNDSDemo

Comment: This article might help, towards the end https://medium.com/@toastui/from-zero-to-publish-expo-web-react-native-for-web-tutorial-e3e020d6d3ff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just follow this tutorial : https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/react-native/en/get-started/

After `expo init`, you should run `npx sb init`, then install `@storybook/react-native-server` (as a devDependency).

Once you're here, just install Jest as seen in the previous link, and run `yarn storybook`. You'll get Storybook running on `localhost:7007`

Comment: According to its [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/react-native-server), `@storybook/react-native-server` _runs alongside the RN on-device UI_, so I'm not sure that this would actually render the components on the web, as @Mohd seems to hope.